# Zeep Operations argument

Tags: python, python-2.7, wsdl, arguments, zeep

I am trying to interact with a WSDL XML Resource. I run "python -mzeep wsdl" from the command line and get a list of Operations with respect to this resource.

Operations

```
Login(Username: xsd:string, Password: xsd:string, TenantID: xsd:string) -> xsd:string

Logout(SessionID: xsd:string) 

Query(body: ns0:_____Query, header:ns0:Auth, _soapheaders={header:ns0:Auth}) -> Code: xsd:String, Records: ns0: ___Records, Slice: ns0: ___SliceResult
```

Using Python 2.7, I am having trouble invoking the Query Operation. The following code runs successfully invoking the Login operation.

```
from zeep import Client, Settings

wsdl = 'wsdl_resource'
settings = Settings(strict=False)
client = Client(wsdl=wsdl, settings=settings)

client.service.Login(Username='user_name', Password='pass_word)
```

The following works providing the following output a unique 'session_id'. In a string format.

However, when trying to use the query opertation:

```
 client.service.Query( , , ,)
```

I am having trouble getting passing the expected arguments, and retrieve the following Records.

If I try the following:

```
client.service.Query(body=' __Query', header='Auth')
```

I get the following response:

```
 {
 'Code': None,
 'Records': None,
 'Slice': None,
 '_raw_elements': deque()
 }
```

Clearly the resource is there, however having trouble obtaining records I assume this is due to not passing the right arguments to client.service.Query( , , ).

Anyone have experience with zeep? Can someone shed some light to understanding the paramaters to be passed to the Query Operation?